# Can extern make a function variable a global variable?

Tags: c, variables, scope, extern, linkage

As I understood `extern` makes a variable --> global variable, so it means we can also make variable of another function a global variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char* name;

void namePrint();

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", name);
    namePrint();
}

void namePrint() {
    printf("%s", name);
    char* name = "Satyam";
}
```

Comment: I have not understood the question.

Comment: You understood `extern` wrong. It's not about making symbols "global". Tells tells the compiler about the existence of a symbol that has been created somewhere else, outside (= lit. *extern*) from the current translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

You understood extern wrong. It's not about making symbols "global". Tells tells the compiler about the existence of a symbol that has been created somewhere else, that is outside (which is literally what the word "extern" means) from the current translation unit.

It's kind of declaring a function before using it. Using `extern` in function declarations is allowed:

```
// someheader.h
extern void foo(void);
```

In fact semantically the usual functions are declared, that is without the use of `extern` is just a *shorthand* for doing it with.

Answer (score 0):

By the term "global variable" C programmers mean variables (with external or internal linkage) having file scope.

Variables declared within functions are local variables and invisible outside the function scope where they are declared.

You could declare within a function a variable that will refer to a variable in file scope using the storage class specifier extern. For example

```
char* name = "Satyam";

void namePrint();

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", name);
    namePrint();
}

void namePrint() {
    extern char* name;
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

Here within the function `namePring` the declared variable `name` refers to the global variable `name` declared in the file scope. That is it denotes the global variable `name`.

Or more meaningful example

```
char* name = "Satyam";

void namePrint();

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", name);
    namePrint();
}

void namePrint() {
    char *name = "Programmer";
    printf( "%s ", name );
    {
        extern char* name;
        printf("%s\n", name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:

As your code is now, it compiles, but doesn't link.

By `extern char* name;` you are telling the compiler that *somewhere* a global variable `name` exists. The compiler is fine with this.

This function:

```c
void namePrint() {
    printf("%s", name);
    char* name = "Satyam";
}
```

uses this global variable in the `printf()` call. The definition of the local variable `name` in the following line is *another* variable with the same name. It would "shadow" the global variable, if there were some code accessing `name` afterwards (it isn't).

Because you never define the global variable `name`, the linker cannot resolve the references.